# How to implement map in Javascript where value is an array of strings similarly as we have in Java?

Tags: javascript, node.js, dictionary, ecmascript-6

I am looking for a way how we can implement HashMap functionality in javascript. I found map() as global object which has been introduced in es6 using which we can do the same.But making a a value as an array doesn't seems to be working.Can anyone help me for the same.
[Map-JavaScript | MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map)

Below is the snippet of the sample code.

```
    var map1 = new Map(); 
    var names=['abc','bcd','abc'];
    for(var i=0;i<name.length;i++){
        if(map1.has(name[i]))
            map1.set(name[i],map1.get(name[i]).push('B'));//if key is already there append B
        else
            map1.set(name[i],['A']);//if key is not present append A
    }

    console.log(map1);
```

I am expecting the value of the key abc as `['A','B']`

Actual Result : 
`Map { 'abc' => 2, 'bcd' => [ 'A' ] }`

Expected Result : 
`Map { 'abc' => ['A','B'],'bcd' => ['A']}`

Comment: Also note that `.push()` returns the new length of the array, not the array itself.

Comment: this is because you are assigning the *result* of `map1.get(name[i]).push('B')` and that result is the new length of the array. You don't need to assign anything - arrays in JS are actually like ArrayLists in Java and can grow normally. Also, since you're storing the array *reference*, any modifications to the array will be "shared" with the map where it's at. Since you're only modifying the same object. Just do `map1.get(name[i]).push('B'))` without doing `map.set` at the same time.

Answer (score 2):

The `Array.prototype.push` returns the size of the new array not the array itself after inserting a new element.

Just do a `Map.get(key)` to get the previous array ***reference*** and push inserted key you don't need to do a `Map.set(key)` again:

```js
var map1 = new Map(); 
const names = ['abc','bcd','abc'];

for(let i=0; i<names.length; i++){
   if(map1.has(names[i])){
      map1.get(names[i]).push('B');
   }
   else{
      map1.set(names[i], ['A'] );
   }
}

console.log(...map1.entries());
```

Also `name` refers to the global variable [`window.name`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/name) so do not use that as a variable name:

```js
console.log(Object.is(name, window.name));
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't use `name` as variable name if you're using `var`, it will conflict with `window.name`, or just use `let name`, or use any other variable name,

Also `push` returns length of the array, so when you do `map1.set(key, x.push('B'))` it will set the length as value to that key not the array, so use `concat` or you can use `...` spread syntax

```js
let map1 = new Map();
let name = ['abc', 'bcd', 'abc'];
for (let i = 0; i < name.length; i++) {
  if(map1.has(name[i])){
    map1.set(name[i], map1.get(name[i]).concat('B'))
  }else{
    map1.set(name[i], ['A'])
  }
}

console.log([...map1]);
```